# How to use an existing ontology in a Java application?

Tags: eclipse, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I've created an ontology with several instances. What I'm going to do with it is :

Using Eclipse, create a searching program. User can input a string, and if an instance has this string as one of its datatype properties, the name and other properties of this instance will be shown to the user.

I really have no idea what plug-ins of eclipse, what grammar, or what other tools I should use. I'm extremely new to semantic web and the relevant tools, so any help will be great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at the [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) as a starting point for using ontologies in a programmatic fashion. It shouldn't be a problem to integrate it with other Eclipse tools.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't realize OWL-API's existence before...I'm now comparing its usage with Jena.

Comment: @goldfrapp04 Depending on what you want to do, Jena's Model and [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) interfaces might be a little bit more convenient.  (I say this having spent lots of time with Jena, and only a little bit with the OWL-API.)

Comment: I would say depending on what information you want to get, you need to choose your API. OWL API is more flexible with OWL, and Jena probably better for RDF. That is my observation at least.